# Connecting My Website to a Cloud DataBase

Tags: javascript, database, web, database-connection, cloud

Please help me out, I have a form-page in my website, i need to save that form details to database. and planning to host DB in a cloud. So Seniors If any one got any Ideas, Suggestions, Code, Links which helps to Connect MY-WEB PAGE and CLOUD DB . . . Please DO POST... Thank YOU ALL

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good place to find full solutions.  There are many places to find tutorials for this sort of thing.  If you have specific questions feel free to come back with them.

Comment: Here is a list of cloud providers for dbs: http://www.networkworld.com/article/2162274/cloud-computing/10-of-the-most-useful-cloud-databases.html come back when you have a question

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a database, you just need a database driver (client) to communicate with your database. If you want to host this in the 'cloud', you will need to do the following:

1. decide on the type of database (sql/nosql)
2. decide whether you are going to host it in the cloud (rackspace, amazon, etc), or use a hosted service (https://cloud.google.com/sql/, object rocket, etc, etc)
3. then connect to it via your db driver

It usually makes most sense to locate your db & web pages close together (same hosting provider) or at least the same country of hosting.

Sorry this is so broad, your question is too broad to do much more than provide pointers where to start.